# Was Jango Fett aware of the true intention of Order 66?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

Jango Fett was used as the template for the Grand Army of the Republic. Was he aware of the plot to kill the Jedi using the clones (Order 66)? In Episode II, *Attack of the Clones*, Fett states:

> "I was recruited by a man called Tyrannus on one of the moons of Bogden."
>
> -Jango Fett, *Attack of the Clones*

Seeing as Tyranus is none other than Count Dooku, was Jango approached with the idea of killing the Jedi?

Comment: You have remember it is Order *66*. Many of these orders are contingency measures. IIRC there were other orders that would negatively affect Palpatine and his cronies as well. I am sure loads of people were aware of them Senators, Jedi, etc.; but just like a modern bill/law who actually reads it! Even if they did would a random contingency order stand out when there seems to be one for completely unthinkable situations.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what we know, there's no reason to assume Jango knew (or cared to know) any details about the clones' enhancements and programming, let alone the most closely guarded secret of the project. They kept him around as a living genetic donner for whenever they needed more material; that seems about the extent of his involvement in the endeavour.

To date, the only people we know were even aware of Order 66 are Palpatine, Dooku, and some senior Kaminoans such as Lama Su & Nala Se. So it appears to have been strictly need-to-know; Maul said even he wasn't privy to the details of the plan, and was just as surprised as the Jedi were when the clones turned.

Indeed; from conversations with Tyranus in the episode ('Conspiricy') it's debatable how much even the Kaminoans actually understood the purpose for which Order 66 was actually intended. Only that it's existence should under no circumstances be revealed to the Jedi.
The very fact that they only knew him as Tyranus and not Dooku seems to support this idea. The details and exact timing of events remain somewhat obscured, but Dooku did claim that Sifo-Dias worked with him to commission the army. We also know from 'Tales of the Jedi' that the plan was already in motion with Dooku's direct involvement before he formally took the name Tyranus, so how the Kaminoans came to know him by that name isn't clear, though one might suppose he just showed up using that name, and somehow convinced the Kaminoans that he was Sifo-Dias' designated representative or proxy. Then proceeded to go recruit Jango as the template.

For his part, Jango only seemed to be motivated by self enrichment (he was paid a LOT of money) and the promise of a legacy in the form of Boba.

Answer (score -4):

Order 66 was explicitly detailed in *Republic Trooper: True Colors*

> In the event of Jedi officers acting against the interests of the Republic, and after receiving specific orders verified as coming
> directly from the Supreme Commander (Chancellor), GAR commanders will remove those officers by lethal force, and command
> of the GAR will revert to the Supreme Commander (Chancellor) until a new command structure is established.

Order 66 was not precisely “any plot to kill the Jedi using the clones” — it was merely a homeland safeguard contingency in case the Jedi, for example following conspiracy theories to accuse the Emperor of being a member of an elite evil cabal who seeks to prolong his life through sacrificing innocents and stage a coup d’etat. If the Jedi didn’t fall prey to their institutional bias against the Sith religion, Palpatine would have had no legal basis to execute Order 66.

Comment: All of which is true, but doesn't answer the original question of whether Jango was aware of it.

Comment: The question “was Jango approached with the idea of killing the Jedi?” is akin to asking whether Oppenheimer was approached in 1942 with idea of killing Hiroshima in 1945; he knew he was making a weapon to kill — his knowledge made him arguably the most dangerous man in the galaxy. Jango certainly knew his clonetroopers were likely going to be used “kill things” — that’s what happens when you requisition a fully outfitted Clone Army.

Comment: Palpatine wasn't forced into Order 66. It was clearly part of his grand plan. We see in The Clone Wars and The Bad Batch that when clone inhibitor chips are activated, they're wired to go straight to Jedi killing.

Comment: The question was "was Jango aware of it in any capacity", actually. If he was approached with the idea is helpful.

Comment: However, it is not the subject of the question.